# SoftKeyboard invalidateKey(Key key) not working as expected

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

i am trying to change a single key label and its miniKeybord(popupKeyboard) resource id its changing label but when i longPress the key its not changing miniKeyboard resource id 
i have toggle button in candidate view from which i want to change the "." to "-" key its changing label but not ResourceID for longPress

this is my toggle method for changing key label and ResourceID

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


    this.editor = this.mSharedPreferences.edit();
    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.easyUrduToggleBtn:
            if (isChecked) {
                this.editor.putBoolean("easy_urdu", true);
                this.mEasyUrdu = shouldChangePunctuationKey = true;
                SoftKeyboard keyboard = (SoftKeyboard) mKeyboardSwitcher.getInputView().getKeyboard();
                keyboard.mPunctuationKey.label = "۔";
                keyboard.mPunctuationKey.codes = new int[]{keyboard.mPunctuationKey.label.charAt(0)};
                keyboard.mPunctuationKey.popupResId = R.xml.popup_punctuation_ur;
                mKeyboardSwitcher.getInputView().invalidateKey(keyboard.mPunctuationKey);

            } else {
                this.editor.putBoolean("easy_urdu", false);
                this.mEasyUrdu = shouldChangePunctuationKey = false;
                SoftKeyboard keyboard = (SoftKeyboard) mKeyboardSwitcher.getInputView().getKeyboard();
                keyboard.mPunctuationKey.label = ".";
                keyboard.mPunctuationKey.codes = new int[]{keyboard.mPunctuationKey.label.charAt(0)};
                keyboard.mPunctuationKey.popupResId = R.xml.popup_punctuation;
                mKeyboardSwitcher.getInputView().invalidateKey(keyboard.mPunctuationKey);
            }
            this.editor.apply();
            return;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

and this is my invalidateKey method in `KeyboardBaseView`

```
 public void invalidateKey(Key key) {
    if (key == null)
        return;
    mInvalidatedKey = key;
    // TODO we should clean up this and record key's region to use in onBufferDraw.
    mDirtyRect.union(key.x + getPaddingLeft(), key.y + getPaddingTop(),
            key.x + key.width + getPaddingLeft(), key.y + key.height + getPaddingTop());
    onBufferDraw();
    invalidate(key.x + getPaddingLeft(), key.y + getPaddingTop(),
            key.x + key.width + getPaddingLeft(), key.y + key.height + getPaddingTop());
}
```

its only changing its label by redrawing it but not miniKeyboardResource id when i long press its showing old miniKeyboard but when i click on next EditText it changing the resource ID because i have check in `class SoftKeyboard extends Keyboard` in this method

```
 @Override
protected Key createKeyFromXml(Resources res, Row parent, int x, int y,
                               XmlResourceParser parser) {
    Key key = new LatinKey(res, parent, x, y, parser);
    switch (key.getCode()) {
        case 46:
            mPunctuationKey=key;
            if (LatinIME.shouldChangePunctuationKey) {
                key.label = "۔";
                key.codes = new int[]{key.label.charAt(0)};
                key.popupResId=R.xml.popup_punctuation_ur;
                mPunctuationKey=key;
                Log.e("akjskjas",1+"");

            } else {
                key.label = ".";
                key.codes = new int[]{key.label.charAt(0)};
                key.popupResId=R.xml.popup_punctuation;
                Log.e("akjskjas",2+"");

            }
            break;
```

but from toggle button its not working its only changes its label not miniKeyboard `key.popupResId` please help me what is the issue